# Como validar se é vogal sem escrever todas as letras do alfabeto

Tags: python

Escreva a função vogal que recebe um único caractere como parâmetro e devolve True se ele for uma vogal e False se for uma consoante.

Note que

vogal("a") deve devolver True

vogal("b") deve devolver False

vogal("E") deve devolver True

Os valores True e False devolvidos devem ser do tipo bool (booleanos)

Dica: Lembre-se que para passar uma vogal como parâmetro ela precisa ser um texto, ou seja, precisa estar entre aspas.

```
vogais = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
letra = ("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")

def vogal():
    input(str("Digite uma letra: "))
    while letra == vogais:
        vogal = "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

Não dá erro no código, mas não está no formato certo, o que eu posso fazer pra deixar mais simples?

Answer (score 17):

Para isto estás longe de precisar de um `while`... ou de ter todas as letras do alfabeto.

Estás também a cometer o erro que não guardar o input numa variável, e não  precisas de o tranformar em string `str(..)` pois o `input()` já retorna uma string por default,

> Os valores True e False devolvidos devem ser do tipo bool (booleanos)

então este retorno, `return "True"`, não está correto, deves retornar sem as aspas senão devolves uma string e não *Boolean*.

Dito isto, podes fazer assim:

```
def vogal(letra):
    vogais = "aeiou"
    if letra.lower() not in vogais: # verificar se a letra digitada minuscula nao existe na nossa variavel vogais
        return False
    return True

letra = input("Digite uma letra: ")
print(vogal(letra)) # aqui imprime True ou False
```

Repara que  `letra.lower()` é para cobrir a hipótese de a letra digitada poder ser maiuscula, e aqui transformamos em minuscula pois as vogais que temos estão também em minuscula.

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/9yv8LX)

A função podia até ser reduzida (com a alternativa sem a função `lower()`) para:

```
def vogal(letra):
    vogais = "aeiouAEIOU"
    return letra in vogais
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 4):

```
def isVogal(letra):
    vogais = 'aeiou'
    return letra.lower() in vogais

def vogal():
    print(isVogal(input("Digite uma letra: ")))


vogal()
```

Criei 2 metodos, onde o primeiro retorna True para vogal e False caso contrario, independente se Caixa alta ou não. O segundo recebe a entrada do usuário e imprime True, para vogais e False para consoantes.

Answer (score 2):

```
def vogal(x):
    if x == "a" or x == "e" or x == "i" or x == "o" or x == "u" or x== "A" or x == "E" or x == "I" or x == "O" or x == "U":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Funciona, mas não é recomendado fazer assim em Python. O código fica difícil de ler e, consequentemente, difícil de manter. Busque sempre a solução *pythonica* do problema.